Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is 37699772
with cte as (
select function_returning_array(start, end) as arr
from my_table
)
select array_agg(value) from cte, table (flatten(cte.arr));

The code above returns the error:
Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is 37699772

How can I improve this code so it will run? I understand the error is coming from the dataset being to large. But I am unfamiliar with the measurements I can take to fix this.

Not really sure what you are asking - you can “improve” your code by not trying to generate a column that contains more than 16Mb of data. If you can update your question with more information about what you’re trying to achieve, sample data, etc then it may be possible to help you further

@NickW the output of the select retrieves an array that should become the input to an alter object set value = output statement.

@NickW Looking at it I am guessing I will need to chop it up into block that do fit in a single column. No clue how that would be done yet…

Maybe consider writing a UDTF instead, which would allow the current array to be returned as a table, instead.  Without knowing more details, though, it's hard for this community to help you.
